# error occured when executing the command npm adduser

Tags: npm

Whatever I typed in, the console printed info like this

```
F:\cmd>npm adduser
Username: lx9542
Password:
Email: (this IS public) lx1412@gmail.com
npm ERR! 200 Could not create user
npm ERR! {"ok":true,"id":"org.couchdb.user:lx9542","rev":"1-e3cdf675f7d7e69b8517
f3f96df274be","_etag":"\"1-e3cdf675f7d7e69b8517f3f96df274be\""}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-14T14_56_55_452Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you looked at the log file mentioned in the error message? What does it say?

Comment: please check https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8198